# Laravel Socialite log out and database storing

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to set up Socialite in Laravel for facebook logging. I got user logged in , but now I have a problem storing the details in the database. 
Also I would like to know how to notice my app that User is logged in? For normal loggin I used native AuthController and everything goes smooth.
Now if user try to log in again, then Laravel automatically redirect it to the url without logging, with appended code like this ?code=AQBCM-KbFqB-VJepSJ-45nFURnsvPPdpdqOu... 
So how can I logout the user completely and how can I store the details for the next logging??

This is what I am using but it is not working:

```
      public function getSocialAuth($provider=null)
       {
           if(!config("services.$provider")) abort('404'); //just to handle providers that doesn't exist

           return $this->socialite->with($provider)->redirect();
       }


       public function getSocialAuthCallback($provider=null)
       {

          if($user = $this->socialite->with($provider)->user()){

      dd($user);

/* This is also not working:
     $user1 = new User;
     $user1->facebook_id = $user->getId();
     $user1->email=$user->email();
         $user1->fullname=$user->name();
         $user1->provider="facebook";
        $user1->save();*/

// not working:

   User::create([
           'facebook_id' => $user->getId(), 'email' => $user->email(),

 'fullname' => $user->name()
        ]);




          }else{
             return 'something went wrong';
          }
       }
```